# Set embedded google map to be zoomed out on page load

Tags: html, google-maps

I have a customised google map embedded into my website. Here is the code for it:

```
<iframe width="640" height="480" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&amp;hl=en&amp;msa=0&amp;msid=115531006415676945149.00048e1de39f5afb920b0&amp;ll=9.226911,-100.82267&amp;spn=0.005083,0.006866&amp;z=17&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small>View <a href="http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&amp;hl=en&amp;msa=0&amp;msid=115531006415676945149.00048e1de39f5afb920b0&amp;ll=9.226911,-100.82267&amp;spn=0.005083,0.006866&amp;z=17&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">Retailers</a> in a larger map</small>
```

What I want to do, is when someone lands on my retailers page, that the map is zoomed out so the user can see the whole world. At the moment, when a user lands on the page, the map is very zoomed in to one particular part of the ocean which is not desirable.

Any help is appreciated! 
thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Zoomlevels

Comment: Do you think it matters that I am not using the API..I literally just made a custom map, and clicked "link" to get the html code.

Comment: Actually, it's okay, I've got it ;-) Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Cool. :) It's just the true and false settings I think but it might give you lots more ideas you might want to try.